# storyboard_with_task

Tags: html, rally

[image] In storyboard.How can i view all the tasks under each user stories,
 with a checkbox beside each task?

something like agilezen?

Comment: Have you seen the Iteration Tracking Board?  http://www.rallydev.com/help/iteration-tracking-board